# How to estimate coefficients for a+xb=c?

Tags: python, r, regression, least-squares

I am trying to find the right python or R package/function to approximate x in the equation `a + xb = c`.

`a`, `b`, and `c` are tuples/vectors, so if I have:

```
a = (1,2,1)
b = (2,3,2)
c = (5,8,5)
```

then I would like the function to give me `x = 2`.

I feel like some form of least squares approach might be the right way to go, but I cannot seem to find a function that does this. Maybe I am looking with the wrong terms, because it seems like such an obvious thing, I don't know.

Comment: Why is this question tagged R?

Comment: You looking for [Linear Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)?

Comment: inside the base R package `stats` there is a function called *confint* which helps create confidence intervals for 1 or more models,  R was literally made for statistics so I am sure you can find exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sympy` for Python , here how it works :

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
solve(x**2 - 1, x)
[-1, 1] # output
```